# Странный результат запроса

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Просветите, почему вывод идет в виде сортировки всех символов подряд.
Вот код:

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] words = { "Avto", "Moto", "Velo", "Photo" };

    var v = from word in words
            let temp = word.ToCharArray()
            from chars in temp
            orderby chars ascending
            select chars;

    foreach (char c in v)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю, что внешний from через переменную temp дает вложенному from массив символов, эти символы конкретного слова сортируются и потом опять поступает новый массив символов, и.т.д.

То есть на выходе я ожидаю, набор отсортированных символов для каждого массива отдельно. А получается, что в это запросе символы всех слов из массива "s" кучкуются вместе, и потом "глобально" сортируются. Почему так происходит? Я ожидал получить примерно следующее на выходе

```
AotvMooteloV...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужен подобный запрос:

```
words
    .Select(word => word
        .ToCharArray()
        .OrderBy(c => c)
    )
    .SelectMany(chars => chars);
```

Здесь каждое слово с помощью `Select` преобразуется в последовательность отсортированных символов. Сортировка символов в слове производится во "вложенном запросе". Затем с помощью `SelectMany` последовательность последовательностей символов сливается в просто последовательность символов.

Ваш запрос эквивалентен следующему:

```
words
    .SelectMany(word => word.ToCharArray())
    .OrderBy(c => c);
```

То есть сначала все символы из всех слов сливаются в один с помощью `SelectMany`, затем сортируются.

Не умею писать в виде запроса, пусть это кто-нибудь другой сделает. :)

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность !! Я все с методами запроса до сих пор не подружился. Буду наверстывать упущенное

Comment: @polyakov_s По-моему, с методами проще: map, filter и т.п. А в запросе всё получается неявно. Запросы удобнее, только если нужны let или слияние больше двух последовтельностей.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что ваш код равносилен такому:

```
var v = s.Select(s => new { s, temp = word.ToCharArray() })
         .SelectMany(pair => pair.temp)
         .OrderBy(c => c);
```

Для того, чтобы получить сортировку внутри каждого слова, попробуйте вложенный запрос:

```
var v = from word in s
        let temp = from chars in word.ToCharArray() 
                   orderby chars ascending
                   select chars
        from chars2 in temp
        select chars2;
```

Обратите внимание, что вы получите `AotvMootVeloPhoot` (а не `...eloV`), т. к. заглавные буквы при сортировке идут перед строчными.

Comment: `temp` лишний, можно заинлайнить.

Comment: @Athari: Ну, не совсем. У нас есть _имя_ `temp`, на которое можно сослаться, если его заинлайнить, то это будет невозможно. `let` в quary syntax соответствует переходу к анонимному классу, я именно это и отобразил. (А так вообще-то конечно код равносилен `s.SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(c => c)`, можно и `ToCharArray` выкинуть.)

Comment: При разворачивании-то можно оставить, чтобы объяснить процессы, но вообще-то можно обойтись без `temp` и в исходном неверном решении, и в вашем: `from word in words from chars in (from cs in word.ToCharArray() orderby cs ascending select cs) select chars`

Comment: @Athari: Ну, я стараюсь не очень отходить от оригинала. `temp` не заинлайнился в первоначальном query, поэтому я его и оставил в ответе. Впрочем, это наверное вкусовщина.

Comment: Если говорить о вкусах, то мне разрывает мозг от монструозности запросовой формы записи в этом случае. `words.Select(w => w.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c)).SelectMany(c => c)` в разы проще и понятнее.

Comment: @Athari: Дело привычки. `OrderBy(c => c)` мне не очень нравится. Ну и попробуйте перевести в адекватный function syntax нетривиальные конструкции с `let`, будет некрасиво и неочевидно. Мне query syntax сначала не нравился, но потом я понял его силу и втянулся.

Comment: Мне довольно редко попадаются запросы, где нужен let. :) Ну и `OrderBy(c=>c)` и `SelectMany(c=>c)` часто обрастают более благозвучными extension методами: `words.Select(w => w.ToCharArray().OrderBySelf()).Flatten()`.

Comment: @Athari: Я бы переименовал `SortBySelf()` в `Ascending()`, a `Flatten()` у меня лежит в файле `EnumerableExtensions.cs` :-) Там ещё комментарий `// TODO: check if this is more efficient than for + yield return`.

Comment: @Athari: А с `let` чем больше я его использую, тем больше он нужен. Даже если без него можно обойтись, он позволяет дать _имя_ промежуточному результату, что на самом деле важно.

Comment: @Athari: Вот пример из текущего кода: http://pastebin.com/atnfEfGY. Без `let` было бы не так наглядно.

Comment: Что ж вы не весь запрос в запросной форме написали? :)

Comment: @Athari: Мне показалось так семантичнее. Конкретика `bee.Convert` не ложилась в смысл, и я её заинлайнил.